# How to differentiate the MS Access and Access Runtime registry keys?

Tags: batch-file

I am currently building a batch file that silently installs MS Access Runtime  based on multiple parameters.

**Instances:**

**1.)** If Runtime or Normal Access (that comes with Office Suite) is not installed, than the batch file installs a version of runtime based on the architecture of the computer (Runtime 32 bit or 64 bit).

**2.)** If normal MS Access is already installed do not install anything.

**3.)** If MS Runtime is already installed do not install anything.

**4.)** If Microsoft Office Suite (2016, 365) is already installed but does not include MS Access, install the version of Access Runtime that's the same architecture (64 bit or 32 bit).

To check if a program is installed, I believe I need to use the reg query.

Then I'll implement conditional statements like:

```
reg query 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{68AB9B5C-20C6-4A96-9185-5C751109C558}

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto OpenNotepad
```

The issue I am having is determining how I can tell what version of MS Access is installed 32 or 64 bit and if Access is even installed. How can I find the registry keys of Runtime 64/32 bit.

Comment: You don't think Microsoft has thought this through. Just install it and trust Microsoft the experts.

Comment: Would you typically get instances where 32bit office is installed on a 64bit device?

Comment: @Noodles Microsoft has two download files 32 and 64, my batch needs to execute one then based on the computers criteria...the executable does not do if itself...

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes that is also an instance but falls under instance #4

Comment: Please read the Microsoft documentation about [Application Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/app-registration) and don't depend on existence of an uninstall key to determine if an application correct registered is installed at all.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late to be helpful but I thought I'd put it down anyways...

To determine if Access/Runtime is installed, it may be easiest to check the following reg key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MSACCESS.EXE
```

To determine which version of Access is installed, you can check for the following registry keys:
For 32-bit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\AccessRuntimeRetail - en-us
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365ProPlusRetail - en-us
```

For 64-bit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\AccessRuntimeRetail - en-us
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365ProPlusRetail - en-us
```